# upload file to google drive folder instead of user browser javascript/jsquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-drive-api

My current script uses the code below to download a CSV file to local drive,

```
function table2CSV() {
var dataURL = '',
fieldSeparator = ',',
textField = '"',
lineSeparator = '\n',
regExpTesto = /(")/g,
regExp = /[";]/;

$('table tr').each(function() {
var dataRow = '';
if ($('input:checkbox', this).is(':checked') || $(this).is(':first-  child'))   
{
  $('td', this).not(':last').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    if (dataRow !== '') dataRow += fieldSeparator;

    if (regExp.test(value)) {
      value = textField + value.replace(regExpTesto, '$1$1') + textField;
    }
    dataRow += value;

  });
  if (dataURL !== '') dataURL += lineSeparator;
  dataURL += dataRow;
}
 });
  window.location.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8;base64,' + btoa(dataURL);
 }
```

The download is done bye this line as far as I can tell :

```
window.location.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8;base64,' + btoa(dataURL);
```

I would like to be able to have it download(upload/saved) to a shared google drive folder instead.
I have seen similar questions on the forum but can't seem to see how to point the download to a shared google-drive folder.
What must code must be added/changed in order to achieve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Nevermind, just realised they say it does not support data URIs:

> Data URIs and file:// URLs are not supported

I will keep this answer in case anyone else searches for non-data URI uploading

---

Having a quick look, I came upon [Save to Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/savetodrive)

While this might not be exactly what you want, it looks like an easy way to add the ability to save the contents of any URI (hopefully a data URI too) to Google Drive, like so:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-savetodrive"
   data-src="//example.com/path/to/myfile.pdf"
   data-filename="My Statement.pdf"
   data-sitename="My Company Name">
</div>
```

Comment: The only way I can think of, is that you post the data to your server and provide a temporary URI for it to be accessed, but this is out of the scope of just client-side JavaScript

Comment: ..I had seen that too .. sadly it wants the file and file path :-( and I would like the file as the file generated by my script